# basic Javascript if/else statement question

Tags: javascript

I'm looking at the following Javascript code, trying to port it to another language:

```
if (x>n) {return q} {return 1-q)
```

I don't know what the code is doing, but can someone tell me based on syntax what occurs? Is there an implied 'else' before the last set of {}? That is, if x>n then return q otherwise return 1-q?

If it helps, here's the line of code it was embedded within:

```
if(x>9000 | n>6000) { var q=Norm((Power(x/n,2/5)+1/(8*n)-1)/Sqrt(9/(2*n)))/3; if (x>n) {return q}{return 1-q} }
```

thanks

Comment: @Jacob Relkin It could be from a compressed java script library i.e. thrown out all spaces and newlines to minimize file size.

Comment: @SemVanmeenen Except it *hasn't* thrown out all meaningless spaces :P

Comment: Unless I'm unaware of something it looks to me like that code is broken.  Pop open firebug console: `if (1>2) {1} {2}` prints 2, all good. `if (3>2) {1} {2}` prints 2... OK...? `if (3>2) {1} else {2}` prints 1.

Comment: yah, the whole code base is like that.

Comment: @Alex Oh, right. Just glanced over it.

Comment: Endophage, yes I edited some of the code/numbers to make it more readable, if you can believe it, to focus on the syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's only an implied else because the block that pairs with the `if` statement returns from the function.  The code you posted is equivalent to:

```
if(x > n)
{
    return q;
}
return q + 1;
```

You only get if/else-like behaviour because the second statement can only be executed if the first statement isn't (because the first statement would return from the function, and control would never get to the second).

This bad code!  For readability / maintainability / sanity, it should be written in one of these more sustainable formats:

```
if(x > n) {return q;}
else      {return q + 1;}
```

Or:

```
return (x > n)? q : q + 1;
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

Its basically this:

```
if (x>n)
   return q; 
else 
   return 1-q;
```

Comment: beautifully answered. Simple as.

Comment: Not true!  It only happens to work because the `if` block returns.  Anything else, say `if(x > n) {x += 12} {x +=7}`, will behave completely differently.  There is _not_ an implied `else`.

Comment: @Xavier - it is with the `return`.

Comment: True, but I think this is a dangerous answer to the more general question of "Does `if(x) {block-1} {block-2}` evaluate as `if(x) {block-1} else {block-2}`?"  You're right in this specific case, but making that assumption globally (which your answer seems to propound) will bite you as soon as `block-1` doesn't have a `return` statement.

Answer (score 2):

There is not an implied 'else', the next set of braces simply defines another compound statement. In this case, it acts like an 'else', but only because the 'if' portion carries a return statement.

Answer (score 1):

There's an implied else.  If x>n, the function returns q.  Otherwise, it goes to the next return statement and returns 1-q.

Comment: Slightly misleading to say "implied else". If there was no `return` in the `if` clause, both clauses would be executed when the test evaluates to true. See http://jsfiddle.net/daybarr/jJCGE/ for code

Comment: With that first return there, the second return would only be reached if the if statement was false.  Hence, the implication of an else. It's stylistically bad, but what he was asking for was the meaning - what would happen if the code executed.  I hope his rewrite would be better code. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

That code is really...

```
if (x > 9000 | n > 6000) {
    var q = Norm((Power(x / n, 2 / 5) + 1 / (8 * n) - 1) / Sqrt(9 / (2 * n))) / 3;
    if (x > n) {
        return q
    } {
        return 1 - q
    }
}
```

Either someone thinks unreadable code is a good idea, or they used a bad minifer.

Answer (score 1):

That block of {} after `return q` is not necessary. there isn't any else statement implied there, it's just that if it passes throught the if statement and return q, what comes next won't be executed anymore, otherwise, it will. Then there is no need to put an else there.